# Pandas: GroupBy Shift And Cumulative Sum

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I want to do `groupby`, `shift` and `cumsum` which seems pretty trivial task but still banging my head over the result I'm getting. Can someone please tell what am I doing wrong. All the results I found online shows the same or the same variation of what I am doing. Below is my implementation.

```
temp = pd.DataFrame(data=[['a',1],['a',1],['a',1],['b',1],['b',1],['b',1],['c',1],['c',1]], columns=['ID','X'])

temp['transformed'] = temp.groupby('ID')['X'].cumsum().shift()
print(temp)

   ID   X   transformed
0   a   1   NaN
1   a   1   1.0
2   a   1   2.0
3   b   1   3.0
4   b   1   1.0
5   b   1   2.0
6   c   1   3.0
7   c   1   1.0
```

This is wrong because the actual or what I am looking for is as below:

```
   ID   X   transformed
0   a   1   NaN
1   a   1   1.0
2   a   1   2.0
3   b   1   NaN
4   b   1   1.0
5   b   1   2.0
6   c   1   NaN
7   c   1   1.0
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: temp2 = temp.groupby('ID').shift()
temp2['ID'] = temp['ID']
temp2.groupby('ID').cumsum()

Although it is just a quick and dirty hack. I like Wen-Bens answer better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `transform()` to feed the separate groups that are created at each level of `groupby` into the `cumsum()` and `shift()` methods.

```
temp['transformed'] = \
    temp.groupby('ID')['X'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift())
```

> ```
>   ID  X   transformed
> 0  a  1   NaN
> 1  a  1   1.0
> 2  a  1   2.0
> 3  b  1   NaN
> 4  b  1   1.0
> 5  b  1   2.0
> 6  c  1   NaN
> 7  c  1   1.0
> ```

For more info on `transform()` please see here:

- https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.08-aggregation-and-grouping.html#Transformation
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/groupby.html#transformation

Comment: Thank you for your help and the links to better understand how transform works.

Answer (score 4):

You need using `apply` , since one function is under `groupby` `object` which is `cumsum` another function `shift` is for all `df`

```
temp['transformed'] = temp.groupby('ID')['X'].apply(lambda x  : x.cumsum().shift())
temp
Out[287]: 
  ID  X  transformed
0  a  1          NaN
1  a  1          1.0
2  a  1          2.0
3  b  1          NaN
4  b  1          1.0
5  b  1          2.0
6  c  1          NaN
7  c  1          1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and the explanation

Answer (score 4):

While working on this problem, as the DataFrame size grows, using lambdas on transform starts to get very slow. I found out that using some DataFrameGroupBy methods (like [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.cumsum.html) and [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) instead of lambdas are much faster.

So here's my proposed solution, creating a `'temp'` column to save the cumsum for each ID and then shifting in a different groupby:

```py
df['temp'] = df.groupby("ID")['X'].cumsum()
df['transformed'] = df.groupby("ID")['temp'].shift()
df = df.drop(columns=["temp"])
```

Comment: I agree with you. Yes, this is a cool trick