# How do I compute the cumlative sum of a column while skipping the first two rows?

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like:

```
                                 capacity_gw  marginal_cost  chained_capacity
Case                   Category
CES - No Storage       Hydro        4.277016       0.000000               NaN
                       Solar        9.774715       0.000000               NaN
                       Wind        11.881870       0.000000          4.277016
                       Nuclear      5.242805      12.689066         14.051731
                       NGCC         2.101907      25.109150         25.933600
                       NGGT         4.638107      32.703513         31.176405
                       Overflow    35.000000     169.679554         33.278312
CES - Storage          Hydro        4.277016       0.000000         37.916419
                       Solar        9.774715       0.000000         72.916419
                       Wind        11.881869       0.000000          4.277016
                       Nuclear      5.242805      12.689066         14.051731
                       NGCC         2.101907      25.109150         25.933600
                       NGGT         2.101907      32.703513         31.176405
                       Overflow    35.000000     169.679554         33.278312
Reference - No Storage Hydro        4.277016       0.000000         35.380219
                       Solar       14.289311       0.000000         70.380219
                       Wind        10.435570       0.000000          4.277016
                       Nuclear      1.143500      12.689066         18.566327
                       NGCC         4.533380      25.109150         29.001897
                       NGGT        17.224408      32.703513         30.145397
                       Overflow    35.000000     169.679554         34.678777
Reference - Storage    Hydro        4.277016       0.000000         51.903185
                       Solar       14.894274       0.000000         86.903185
                       Wind        10.435570       0.000000          4.277016
                       Nuclear      1.143500      12.689066         19.171290
                       NGCC         4.533380      25.109150         29.606860
                       NGGT        14.524706      32.703513         30.750360
                       Overflow    35.000000     169.679554         35.283740
```

I have created the `chained_capacity` variable by using:

```py
stack['chained_capacity'] = stack.groupby('Case')['capacity_gw'].cumsum().shift(2)
```

But this is not the result I want. As you can see it's still starting the sum with the first initial value in the column. I want the sum to start with on the 3rd value. So the expected output would be:

```
                                 capacity_gw  marginal_cost  chained_capacity
Case                   Category
CES - No Storage       Hydro        4.277016       0.000000               NaN
                       Solar        9.774715       0.000000               NaN
                       Wind        11.881870       0.000000         11.881870
                       Nuclear      5.242805      12.689066         17.124674
                       NGCC         2.101907      25.109150         17.12 + 2.10
                       NGGT         4.638107      32.703513         ...
                       Overflow    35.000000     169.679554         ...
...
```

Here is `df.to_dict()` to be able to reproduce the data completely:

```
{'capacity_gw': {('Reference - No Storage', 'Solar'): 14.289311043873823, ('Reference - No Storage', 'Wind'): 10.43556981658827, ('Reference - No Storage', 'Hydro'): 4.277016, ('Reference - No Storage', 'Nuclear'): 1.1435, ('Reference - No Storage', 'NGCC'): 4.533380090390558, ('Reference - No Storage', 'NGGT'): 17.22440836569597, ('Reference - No Storage', 'Overflow'): 35.0, ('Reference - Storage', 'Solar'): 14.894274398144354, ('Reference - Storage', 'Wind'): 10.435569838806854, ('Reference - Storage', 'Hydro'): 4.277016, ('Reference - Storage', 'Nuclear'): 1.1435, ('Reference - Storage', 'NGCC'): 4.533380082818851, ('Reference - Storage', 'NGGT'): 14.524706430121823, ('Reference - Storage', 'Overflow'): 35.0, ('CES - No Storage', 'Solar'): 9.774714739869358, ('CES - No Storage', 'Wind'): 11.881869635856951, ('CES - No Storage', 'Hydro'): 4.277016, ('CES - No Storage', 'Nuclear'): 5.242805, ('CES - No Storage', 'NGCC'): 2.1019069999999997, ('CES - No Storage', 'NGGT'): 4.638107074198996, ('CES - No Storage', 'Overflow'): 35.0, ('CES - Storage', 'Solar'): 9.774714538236491, ('CES - Storage', 'Wind'): 11.881869305881622, ('CES - Storage', 'Hydro'): 4.277016, ('CES - Storage', 'Nuclear'): 5.242805, ('CES - Storage', 'NGCC'): 2.1019069999999997, ('CES - Storage', 'NGGT'): 2.1019069999999997, ('CES - Storage', 'Overflow'): 35.0}, 'marginal_cost': {('Reference - No Storage', 'Solar'): 0.0, ('Reference - No Storage', 'Wind'): 0.0, ('Reference - No Storage', 'Hydro'): 0.0, ('Reference - No Storage', 'Nuclear'): 12.68906562274404, ('Reference - No Storage', 'NGCC'): 25.10914978408783, ('Reference - No Storage', 'NGGT'): 32.703513055654646, ('Reference - No Storage', 'Overflow'): 169.6795540944021, ('Reference - Storage', 'Solar'): 0.0, ('Reference - Storage', 'Wind'): 0.0, ('Reference - Storage', 'Hydro'): 0.0, ('Reference - Storage', 'Nuclear'): 12.68906562274404, ('Reference - Storage', 'NGCC'): 25.10914978408783, ('Reference - Storage', 'NGGT'): 32.703513055654646, ('Reference - Storage', 'Overflow'): 169.6795540944021, ('CES - No Storage', 'Solar'): 0.0, ('CES - No Storage', 'Wind'): 0.0, ('CES - No Storage', 'Hydro'): 0.0, ('CES - No Storage', 'Nuclear'): 12.68906562274404, ('CES - No Storage', 'NGCC'): 25.10914978408783, ('CES - No Storage', 'NGGT'): 32.703513055654646, ('CES - No Storage', 'Overflow'): 169.6795540944021, ('CES - Storage', 'Solar'): 0.0, ('CES - Storage', 'Wind'): 0.0, ('CES - Storage', 'Hydro'): 0.0, ('CES - Storage', 'Nuclear'): 12.68906562274404, ('CES - Storage', 'NGCC'): 25.10914978408783, ('CES - Storage', 'NGGT'): 32.703513055654646, ('CES - Storage', 'Overflow'): 169.6795540944021}}
```

Comment: What happens if you `shift` before `cumsum` like `.shift(2).cumsum()`?

Comment: Seems like this may answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993050/pandas-groupby-shift-and-cumulative-sum

Comment: @JoshuaVoskamp That works across `Case` but it doesn't solve the original problem of only starting at the 3rd entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using tricks from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993050/pandas-groupby-shift-and-cumulative-sum), either

```py
# this transform may be slow for large dataframes
stack['chained_capacity'] = \
    stack.groupby('Case')['capacity_gw'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift(2))
```

or

```py
# creates a temporary column; should be fast/scalable for large df
stack['temp'] = stack.groupby('Case')['capacity_gw'].cumsum()
stack['chained_capacity'] = stack.groupby('Case')['temp'].shift(2)
stack = stack.drop(columns=['temp'])
```

Comment: Actually this doesn't work completely, It seems to sum across `Case`, I need the cumulative sum for each `Case`.

Comment: Would you be able to provide a sample `df.to_dict()` to work with?

Comment: I've edited my question to contain that info.

Comment: I also was able to get the right answer by combining your original solution with the solution you linked me, so this: `stack.groupby('Case')['capacity_gw'].transform(lambda x: x.shift(-2).cumsum().shift(2))`

Comment: I may be mistaken; I think the `.shift(-2)` idea I had is entirely unnecessary.

Comment: When I remove `.shift(-2)` I don't get the expected answer. Keeping it in, gives me the answer I'm expecting.